# Formula with quotes into cell using VBA throws error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a code below which concatenate Values in A and B columns. When I want to add an empty space between A and B which is an Excel formula 
   `=CONCATENATE(A4," ",B4)` or `=A4 & " " & B4`
the macro would flag it as an error when using VBA:

```
With ws3.Range("E4:E" & LastRow3)
    .Formula = "=A4&B4"
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this alternatively:

```
For i = 4 to LastRow3
    Cells(i, 5).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & Cells(i, 2).Value
Next
```

This is simple loop, that loops thorugh fifth (E) column, rows between 4 and `LastRow3` and sets the value of this cell to concatenated A and B columns in the same rows.

Comment: Thank you, Michal!

Comment: @BatyrNazarov You should accept answer if it has helped you (optionally upvote).

Comment: @BatyrNazarov Refer to this: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Thanks. So it's a tick which needs to be clicked and then it becomes green)) Thank you)

Answer (score 3):

Quotes within quotes need to be doubled

```
.Formula = "=A4 & "" "" & B4"
```

and this will result in `=A4 & " " & B4` as a formula.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to work:

```
Sub jhgfd()
    Set ws3 = ActiveSheet
    LastRow3 = 10

    With ws3.Range("E4:E" & LastRow3)
        .Formula = "=A4 & CHAR(32) & B4"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

"Translating" a formula from Excel to VBA is probably the most popular task that a person has to do in VBA. This is an algorithm for it:

- Write the formula, so it works in Excel;
- Select it manually;
- Run this:

---

```
Public Sub PrintMeUsefulFormula()

    Dim strFormula  As String
    Dim strParenth  As String

    strParenth = """"

    strFormula = Selection.Formula
    strFormula = Replace(strFormula, """", """""")

    strFormula = strParenth & strFormula & strParenth
    Debug.Print strFormula

End Sub
```

- It prints the formula as it should look like in the immediate window;
- Copy it;

If you follow these steps with `=CONCATENATE(A4," ",B4)`, it prints `"=CONCATENATE(A4,"" "",B4)"`

If you are using local Excel formulas, e.g. a Russian Excel, where `=CONCATENATE()` is `=СЦЕПИТЬ()`, in order to get the local formula printed you should write `Selection.FormulaLocal` instead of `Selection.Formula`.